# Is it possible to have props in vue.js inferred as default instead of undefined?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
// LimitVue.vue
import type { PropType } from 'vue'

props: {
  limit: {
    type: Number as PropType<Number | null>,
    default: null
  }
}
```

I use vue.js option api.

The limit prop can be either a number or null, so it is defined as shown above.

However, when used, the limit prop is inferred as Number | null | undefined.

[image: Number | null | undefined]

Is there a way to exclude undefined and have it inferred as Number | null only?

I know that replacing `default: null` with `required: true` solves this problem.

I want to enable it while using `default`.

Comment: The problem may be specific to your ide. Make sure this is not the case